# Polling Pattern for Silverlight 4 WCF Ria Services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am creating an application in Silverlight using Ria Services that can take quite a bit of time once the service call is initiated.  I've looked for ways to increase the WCF service timeout, but the more I think it through, this is not the right aproach.

What I would rather do is call the DomainContext and return right away, then have the client poll the server to find out when the long running query is complete.

I'm looking for a pattern or example of a good way to implement something like this.  One potential issue that keeps coming to mind are that web services should not keep state between service calls, but this is exactly what I would be doing.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [WCF Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm currenly using Ria services, which are WCF services, but it looks like it would require a lot of refactoring to get this up and running.  I probably won't use Ria ever again because of the issues I've had, but I need to stick with it for this project.  I was able to get close to a solution by creating a Singleton on the server and spawning multiple threads, but as soon as the calling thead to the service returns, the ObjectContext gets disposed and my worker thread dies when hitting the entities.  I'm really stuck here.

Comment: @Scott: even if you solve that, you don't know what to return to each client once you have various clients polling at the same time.

Comment: I am assigning a token to each caller that requests the transaction be broken into pieces.  The client then polls the server using that token to see if the results are there yet.  I'm basically keeping the results in the heap until the client takes it, or it gets deleted by a another process that keeps things clean.  It looks good on paper, but losing the ObjectContext as soon as the calling thread leaves the service was not somthing I was expecting.  Thanks for the reply though...  It's going to be a looong night...

Comment: @Scott: so you're looking for a way to clone/copy the ObjectContext instance? That apparently would solve the problem you described. I gotta log out now. But please, let us know how/if you solved this problem. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the service call take less time?  If not, why not?

Typically when I've seen queries take this long, it either means the SQL running at the end isn't efficient enough, the SQL server has poor indexes, or the client is requesting far more data than they'll actually be able to use in a short period of time.

For example, instead of requesting 500 entities right away and showing a large list/DataGrid/whatever, why not request 10-50 at a time and have a paging UI that only requests the next batch when the user nedes it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am searching against a search index that, depending on the terms searched, could bring back thousands of rows.  I am not able to "skip" X number of results on the query, or I would implement some kind of paging system.  I really need all the results - if not right away, within a short period of time after the search.  This is why I figured I could save the sate of the full query on the server, and come back and get it when it's done.  I agree with you that this is too much data to bring back at once, but I can't find any other way.  Other suggestions?

Comment: Is it because you don't control the search index you're querying?  I think the "most RIA Services way" in that case would be to increase the timeout, not to poll - the `DomainContext` will just take a lot longer to populate, so your UI should have some kind of indicator while the `LoadOperation` is in progress, but eventually it'll all populate with `INotifyCollectionChanged` events and such to update the UI.

Comment: Of course, I would suggest you talk to the owners of the index you're querying and let them know "hey, I'm going to request way more of your data than I need and cost you lots more bandwidth and such...if you could expose the data in a paged way to me, it'd be better for both of us" and see what they say.  Maybe they'd be amenable to that since it benefits both of you, and any future customers of this index :)  Never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at signalr, it can run side by side with ria and it lets you push messages back to the client from the server.

Comment: I have a similiar situation with WCF RIA and silverlight. Do you have any sample code how to use signalR side by side with wcf ria ?

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
look at the samples, they have one for Silverlight as well.